# How can I connect/synchronise Office365 Exchange with my Azure Portal AD?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365, exchange-server

I have an Office365 Exchange server where I host my corporate email.
I also have an Azure subscription with some services (webapp, database, etc.)

What I want to achieve is that the users I create on Exchange (user@mycompany.com) can log in to the Azure portal using the same credentials, and I can grant permissions to some of them to administer Azure resources.
Basically SSO between Offce365 Exchange and Azure portal.

Please note I have nothing "on premises".

Answer (score 0):

If it is only some users, you can invite them as guest users in the AAD tenant you have linked to the Azure subscriptions.
This way they can still use the same credentials and you can give them RBAC roles in the Azure subscriptions/resource groups/resources.

Another possible way might be to change the linked tenant to your Office 365 AAD tenant.
Do note this would erase all RBAC role assignments and they would need to be re-done.
Also anyone needing access to the Azure subscriptions would need to exist as a user/guest in the Office 365 tenant then.
This might be best if only users from this Office 365 tenant use the subscriptions.

Comment: How do I change the linked tenant? Currently I have two users only in Azure so redoing is not a problem. But I guess the current "owner" won't loose the access, right?

Comment: The subscription admin would not lose access, as long as they are also in the other tenant. You can see some guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory